# Can a certificate lead to more than one valid certificate chain during validation'?

Tags: certificate

Is it possible that there are more than one certificate chain built during the validation of a certificate? Maybe in the cross-certificate scenario?

I was trying to understand the cross-certification methode, and it leaves me confused if in such a scenario a validation of a user certificate might lead to obtaining two certificate chains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a known issue with one of the largest PKIs in the world, relating to multiple ways it can chain.  Part of this problem came out with that specific PKI due to initial CA roots later on receiving signatures from other CAs that I believe in effect subordinated them 'slightly'.

However, most people don't understand this since PKI is a niche, and even those that understand it, don't always understand chaining and other.

Well, you are in the big leagues now :)